# Update image preview at firebase storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

i'm with a little problem at firebase. I created a simple upload system where my app users can sent yours photos. 
The system is simple, the user send the image to the storage, and the app save the url at firestore and i use the url in my app to show the image. I improved the system creating one cloud function to make some adjustments on the image. The problem is, when a new photo is uploaded to the storage is showing the older one and not the new image, i don't know if this is something about cache or other configuration that i need to do. In the app is showing the new image but at firebase is showing the older picture, is there any configuration to solve this problem?

Here is my function code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage';
import * as sharp from 'sharp';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';
import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { join, dirname } from 'path';

/* Variaveis Globais */
const gcs = new Storage();

/* Criando o metodo principal */
export const generateThumbs = functions.storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize(async object => {

        /* Instanciando as constantes */
        const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
        const filePath = object.name;
        const contentType = object.contentType;
        const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
        const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);
        const customMetadata = object.metadata;

        /* Criando o diretorio e o path temporario */
        const workingDir = join (tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
        const tmpFilePath = join (workingDir, 'source.png');

        /* Verificando se a imagem e a default */
        if (fileName.includes('default')) {
            console.log ('Imagem default não pode ser alterada, saindo da função....');
            return false;
        }

        /* Verificando se o customMetadata existes */
        if ( typeof customMetadata['edited'] === "undefined") {
            customMetadata['edited'] = "false";
        }

        /* Verificando se a imagem e JPEG ou se ja foi alterada */
        if (!object.contentType.includes('image/') || customMetadata['edited'].includes('true')) {
            console.log ('O arquivo já foi alterado ou não é uma imagem, saindo da função...');
            return false;
        }

        /* 1. Garantido que o diretorio do thumbnail existe */
        await fs.ensureDir (workingDir);

        /* 2. Fazendo o download do arquivo de origem */
        console.log ('Fazendo o download do arquivo no path: ' + filePath);
        await bucket.file(filePath).download({
            destination: tmpFilePath
        });

        /* 3. Redimensionando as imagens e definindo o array de promisses  */
        //const sizes = [64, 128, 256];
        const sizes = [256];

        const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
            console.log ('Redimensionando a imagem e convertendo para JPEG.');
            //const thumbName = `thumbs@${size}_${fileName}`;
            const thumbName = `${fileName}`;
            const thumbPath = join (workingDir, thumbName);

            /* Redimensionando a imagem de origem */
            await sharp (tmpFilePath)
                .resize(size, size)
                .toFormat('jpeg')
                .toFile(thumbPath);

            /* Upload para o GCS */
            console.log('Fazendo o upload para o GCS.');
            return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
                destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
                metadata: {
                    contentType: contentType,
                    metadata: {
                        'edited': 'true'
                    },
                }
            });

            /* Atualizando os metadatas */
        });

        /* Realizando o upload */
        console.log('Fazendo o upload do promisse');
        await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

        /* Limpando os arquivos temporarios */
        console.log ('Removendo os arquivos temporarios e finalizando...');
        return fs.remove (workingDir);

    });
```

Comment: "In the app is showing the new image but at firebase is showing the older picture" I don't understand what you mean here. What is "at firebase"?

Comment: When I look through the web interface of the firebase in the storage tab the old image is displayed, not the new image. If I send a new image with the same name as an old image, the old image is displayed instead of the new image.

Comment: You can disable the cache of sharp with 'sharp.cache(false)'.
Maybe this helps.